# Accordion table showing another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set an accordion in multiple tables.
Once user clicks on a `<tr>`, another table shows at the bottom.

### HTML

```
    <table class="table m-0 stocks" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parent-clickable">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td colspan="5">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
              <td>+</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("parent-clickable").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).closest("tr").find(".hidden").slideToggle(200, "linear");
  });
  console.log("Clicked");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1h7pu3uL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some little things to fix in your code, HTML is fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".parent-clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".hidden").slideToggle(200, "linear");
    console.log("Clicked");
  });

});
```

You forgot to add the selector in front of "parent-clickable" in this case, a class so prefix it with a dot.

using .closest and .find seems redudant in this case, when a single .next can help achieve what you want. Finally, if you are not using it elsewhere, there's no need to store all this in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(".parent-clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").next(".hidden").slideToggle(200, "linear");

    console.log("Clicked");
  });
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.parent-clickable {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table m-0 stocks" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="parent-clickable">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>+</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td colspan="5">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th>Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Mark</td>
              <td>Otto</td>
              <td>@mdo</td>
              <td>+</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
 $(".parent-clickable").on("click", function() {
   　$(this).closest("tr").next(".hidden").slideToggle(200, "linear");
   console.log("Clicked");
 });
```

How about this? A missing . on the parent-clickable selector and use next instead of find?